# Difficulty in Choosing a target on building and running Android source code on OSX

Tags: android, macos, unix, android-source

---

I am on an OSX Mavericks machine. I am following the steps from http://source.android.com/source/building.html

I created android.dmg disk image "case-sensitive and journaled" as suggested. Did $sync repo successfully. 
I did initialize by :

```
     $ source build/envsetup.sh
```

and got:

```
including device/samsung/maguro/vendorsetup.sh
including device/samsung/tuna/vendorsetup.sh
including device/ti/panda/vendorsetup.sh
including sdk/bash_completion/adb.bash
```

Then in my WORKING_DIRECTORY, I executed the command and haven't been able to go further.

```
$lunch 

You're building on Darwin

Lunch menu... pick a combo:
     1. full-eng
     2. full_x86-eng
     3. vbox_x86-eng
     4. full_maguro-userdebug
     5. full_tuna-userdebug
     6. full_panda-eng

Which would you like? [full-eng] 

-bash: cd: /Volumes/Disk: No such file or directory
-bash: cd: /Volumes/Disk: No such file or directory
-bash: cd: /Volumes/Disk: No such file or directory
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=4.0.1
TARGET_PRODUCT=full
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a
HOST_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=darwin
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=ITL41D
============================================
```

I do not understand why it says "No such file or directory", while I am inside that disk space? What is the problem here? please help.

Comment: Is the directory name really "/Volumes/Disk"? Not "/Volumes/Disk with spaces in the name"?

Comment: Thanks for you effort @MagnusBäck. I solved the problem. The default name it produced when I mounted a *.dmg partition was /Volumes/Disk Image. While the 'lunch' command was looking for disk space named /Volumes/Disk.

Comment: Yes, avoid spaces in directory names if you don't want to see breakage everywhere.